# JPA how to set column type to be BLOB for ElementCollection table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot with Hibernate JPA with the following code in my entity class,

```
@ElementCollection
private Map<String, String> userFiles= new HashMap<>();
```

Where a collection table `user_files` is generated. However the default column type is `VARCHAR(255)` and sometimes user data can be longer than that. My question is how can I define this table to use `BLOB` or `TEXT` for column? I tried to throw in `@Lob` annotation directly there but does not work.

Comment: for what, key or value of the map?

Comment: Should have been clearer. For map value, which is based on user input and can be long.

Comment: I would expect the `@Lob` annotation to be applied to the value, as you said you tried. Certainly the _orm.xml_ XSD allows `<lob>` under `<element-collection>` so that implies it should work. Maybe raise an issue on your JPA provider, or consult their docs since there are no other obvious places that I see

Comment: Other than using @Column of course, but then that means using "columnDefinition" which is a crappy database-specific String defintion so not very portable across datastores

Comment: Yeah, that probably would work too. As I replied in the other answer, my mistake was retrying without dropping the table first, I thought JPA will automatically apply new type to existing table but I was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
@Column(columnDefinition="BLOB NOT NULL")
@MapKeyColumn(columnDefinition="BLOB NOT NULL")
```

See [MapKeyColumn](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyColumn.html) and [Lob](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Lob).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did find these annotations before, but I made a mistake that I should have dropped the previously created table first otherwise JPA won't create new table using the new config. Your answer guided me to retry and finally figured out that.