# How to change column type for Hashmap's value to LONGTEXT with JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hashmap

I have an entity with the following fields:

```
public class P_TABLE2  {

    ...................


    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "P_TABLE1",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "P_ID", referencedColumnName = "P_ID",
                    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "none", value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))}
    )
    @MapKeyColumn(name="P_KEY")
    @Column(name = "P_VALUE")
    private Map<String, String> bookmarks;

}
```

Hibernate creates the table P_TABLE1 with following column names:

```
P_ID      | P_KEY         | P_VALUE
bigint    |  varchar(255) | varchar(255)
```

I would like to change the data type of P_VALUE from varchar(255) to LONGTEXT.
I tried everything, but nothing works.

```
@Column(name="P_VALUE", columnDefinition="CLOB")
@Column(name="P_VALUE", columnDefinition="TEXT")
@Lob @Column(name="P_VALUE", columnDefinition="TEXT") ====> ERROR
```

Any suggestions? Pls help me.

PS: I see this question
[JPA how to set column type to be BLOB for ElementCollection table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255965/jpa-how-to-set-column-type-to-be-blob-for-elementcollection-table)
but if I change the column @Column(name="P_VALUE") to @Column(name="P_VALUE", columnDefinition="BLOB"), it does not work. I deleted the table P_TABLE1 in the datbase, and tried to regenerate the table, but no table is created.

Comment: FYI - @Column(name="P_VALUE", columnDefinition="TEXT") worked using JPA/Hibernate with Postgres 13

Comment: Sorry for taking your time. I forgot to delete the table. I tried @Column(name="P_VALUE", columnDefinition="TEXT") and it actually works. Is there any way we don't have to delete the table? I already have some records on this.

Comment: You would have to check your database docs to figure out how to issue an update statement, but I don't think it possible. Best bet is to issue an update table statement to create a new column, another to copy the data over to it, and then have your JPA model use the new column.